# JFrame opens up very small

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My `JFrame` for my program opens up extremely small, I have looked at a couple similar problems and fixes but none have worked so far...

[image]

I am completely stumped with this, usually when I use the jframes it never does this, have I forgotten something simple?

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pkgfinal.project;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author conor
 */
public class SolBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    private final int[][] laysout = {
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,}
    };
    
    private final javax.swing.JButton[][] Board = new javax.swing.JButton[7][7];
     
    
    public SolBoard() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
       
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++){
                if(laysout[i][j]==1) {
                    Board[i][j] = new javax.swing.JButton();
                    Board[i][j].setText(i + "," + j);
                    Board[i][j].setBounds(j*60 + 10, i*60 + 10, 50, 50 );
                    
                    Board[i][j].addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                        javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton) e.getSource();
                        System.out.println(button.getActionCommand());
                    });
                    
                    getContentPane().add(Board[i][j]);
                }        
            }
        }
        getContentPane().add(new javax.swing.JButton("v.1.0"));
    }
    
    
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Board.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        
        //</editor-fold>
    

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            
            new SolBoard().setVisible(true);
            
        });
    }
}
```

It should open to the size of the board (array of buttons)

Comment: probably the frame hasn't got any size... so maybe you should call `pack` or `setSize`

Comment: and you should also consider using a `LayoutManager` instead of constant positions/size for the components....

Comment: Also, you should use a LayoutManager to position the sub-components. Trying to set them at specific locations is a recipe for great frustration. And since you did not set the layout manager to null, the default will be used (a BorderLayout), and therefore your location specifications will be ignored and all items will be placed in CENTER, so only the last item added will be displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `initComponents()` method write:

```
setSize(400, 400);
setVisible(true);//call at the end of initiComponents method
```

then adjust size to your liking. You may also use `setPreferredSize`, `setMinimumSize`, `setMaximumSize` methods or `setExtendedState` to get full screen window.

Example of full screen mode:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
setUndecorated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this put this code in your `initComponents()`:

```
this.setVisible(true);
this.getContentPane().setSize(400, 400);
```

Or this:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
this.pack();
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setVisible(true);
```

I think that the order matters in this case